# jQuery Validate Radio Button with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

During the submission of my form, I need to validate my radio buttons to see if they were selected.

My page layout asks for the education level in multiple fields like so:

[image]

My code for the options look like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="proficiency[journalism]" value="4yr">
<input type="radio" name="proficiency[journalism]" value="working">
<input type="radio" name="proficiency[journalism]" value="some">
<input type="radio" name="proficiency[journalism]" value="none">
```

I need to be able to loop through name="proficiency[journalism]" and say if none of them were selected, throw an error.

I just need to make sure at least one has been selected.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ( $('input:checked[name="proficiency[journalism]"]').length > 0 ) {
    // success
} else {
    // error
}
```

The conditional verifies that there is at least one checked input of that name (you can only select one since it is a radio type), and performs the else function if nothing was selected.

Comment: Can a selector have an array in it?

Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checked[name="proficiency[journalism]"

Comment: It's not an array, it's the string value of the "name" attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/Paul_Geronca/5JX4V/